# filter() collection does not work in subquery

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I am trying to get users which have addresses and the time of creation of that address should not be more than 7 days:

```
$users = User::whereHas('address', function($q) {
        $q->where(function ($query) {
             $query->get()->filter(function ($address) {
                 return Carbon::now() < Carbon::parse($address->getOriginal('created_at'))->addDays(7);
             });
         });
     });
```

the `filter()` works correct but I can't return its results, my result is all users who have addresses.

Comment: You're adding too many steps. Get rid of the filter, and just search for created_at on `$q`. You're still in the query builder, so you cannot use Collection functions.

Comment: @aynber when I dd($q) i have error and can not get address()  but the dd($query) returns it, this is my error :SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `addresses` where `users`.`id` = `addresses`.`user_id`)

Comment: `$query->get()` is returning all addresses, then filtering on created_at, and completely ignoring the relationship. If you're getting `users.id` is not found, then you need to check the Users table schema, and update your relationship accordingly. What is the primary key for your users table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `whereDate` like this:

```php
$users = User::whereHas('address', function ($q) {
    $q->whereDate('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(7));
})->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this

```
$user = User::where('address',date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days')))->where('created_at',date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days')))->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code with comments

```
$users = User::whereHas('address', function ($q): void {
    $q->where(function ($query): void {
        /**
         * Subqueries use Eloquent Builder class here to add some wrapped filters 
         * But your code takes all addresses, filter them for nothing
         * You should add SQL filters to builder something like that:
         **/
        $query->whereDate(Carbon::now()->subDays(7), '<', 'created_at');
    })
    /** To get users by your filters */
    ->get();
```